# Overlay two animations within the same window with FuncAnimation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am writing a program which simulates the motion of the double pendulum. In order to make the impact of different initial values visible, I would like to overlay the motion of two double pendulums onto each other in a single window/graph.

However I have **difficulties with putting the two animations into a single window and overlying each other.** The furthest I have come is opening them in two windows in parallel time, this is done by the provided code.

Furthermore for some reason when I run the code **it generates three windows instead of two, one of which is empty.**

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

loc1 = "DoublePendRes1.txt"
loc2 = "DoublePendRes2.txt"

def calculate_coordinates(L1, L2, angle1, angle2):
    x1 = L1 * np.sin(angle1)
    y1 = -L1 * np.cos(angle1)
    x2 = x1 + L2 * np.sin(angle2)
    y2 = y1 - L2 * np.cos(angle2)
    return x1, y1, x2, y2

def pendulumAnimation(timeLst, angle1Lst, angle2Lst, L1, L2, ax, color):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal', autoscale_on=False, xlim=(-(L1 + L2), L1 + L2), ylim=(-(L1 + L2), L1 + L2))
    ax.grid()
    line, = ax.plot([], [], 'o-', lw=2, color=color)
    trail, = ax.plot([], [], 'r-', alpha=0.6, linewidth=0.8, color=color)

    trail_x = []
    trail_y = []

    def init():
        line.set_data([], [])
        trail.set_data([], [])
        return line, trail

    def update(frame):
        angle1 = angle1Lst[frame]
        angle2 = angle2Lst[frame]
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = calculate_coordinates(L1, L2, angle1, angle2)
        line.set_data([0, x1, x2], [0, y1, y2])

        trail_x.append(x2)
        trail_y.append(y2)
        trail.set_data(trail_x, trail_y)

        return line, trail

    animation = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=len(timeLst), interval=10, init_func=init, blit=True)
    return animation

def extract_data(targetFile):
    dataSet = np.loadtxt(targetFile)

    timeData = dataSet[:, 0]
    theta1Set = dataSet[:, 1]
    theta2Set = dataSet[:, 2]

    return timeData, theta1Set, theta2Set

def animationCall():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.grid()

    time_evo1, theta1_1, theta2_1 = extract_data(loc1)
    animation1 = pendulumAnimation(time_evo1, theta1_1, theta2_1, 1, 1, ax, color='blue')

    time_evo2, theta1_2, theta2_2 = extract_data(loc2)
    animation2 = pendulumAnimation(time_evo2, theta1_2, theta2_2, 1, 1, ax, color='red')

    plt.show()

animationCall()
```

The .txt files are generated by a different program (which later will be written in C++, thus the programs are independent). Note that I still haven't double checked these double pendulum equations but for the questions sake that's irrelevant. You can generate these double pendulum data for your own with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# File loactions for: read/write
loc1 = "DoublePendRes2.txt"

def double_pendulum(t, y, L1, L2, m1, m2):
    theta1, theta1_dot, theta2, theta2_dot = y
    g = 9.8

    c = np.cos(theta1 - theta2)
    s = np.sin(theta1 - theta2)

    # Compute the equations of motion
    theta1_ddot = -(g * (2 * m1 + m2) * np.sin(theta1) + m2 * g * np.sin(theta1 - 2 * theta2) + 2 * s * m2 * (theta2_dot ** 2 * L2 + theta1_dot ** 2 * L1 * c)) / (L1 * (2 * m1 + m2 - m2 * c ** 2))
    theta2_ddot = (2 * s * (theta1_dot ** 2 * L1 * (m1 + m2) + g * (m1 + m2) * np.cos(theta1) + theta2_dot ** 2 * L2 * m2 * c)) / (L2 * (2 * m1 + m2 - m2 * c ** 2))

    dydt = [theta1_dot, theta1_ddot, theta2_dot, theta2_ddot]
    return dydt

# Define the Runge-Kutta-4 method
def runge_kutta_step(t, y, h, L1, L2, m1, m2):
    k1 = h * np.array(double_pendulum(t, y, L1, L2, m1, m2))
    k2 = h * np.array(double_pendulum(t + h/2, y + k1/2, L1, L2, m1, m2))
    k3 = h * np.array(double_pendulum(t + h/2, y + k2/2, L1, L2, m1, m2))
    k4 = h * np.array(double_pendulum(t + h, y + k3, L1, L2, m1, m2))

    return y + (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4) / 6

def solve_double_pendulum(t_span, y0, h, L1, L2, m1, m2):
    num_steps = int((t_span[1] - t_span[0]) / h)
    t_values = np.linspace(t_span[0], t_span[1], num_steps + 1)
    y_values = np.zeros((num_steps + 1, 4))
    y_values[0] = y0

    for i in range(num_steps):
        t = t_values[i]
        y = y_values[i]
        y_values[i + 1] = runge_kutta_step(t, y, h, L1, L2, m1, m2)

    return t_values, y_values

def doublePendulumCall(initLst, L1, L2, m1, m2):
    #Initail Conditions: [theta1, theta1_dot, theta2, theta2_dot]
    y0 = initLst

    # Time span for the simulation
    t_span = (0, 10)
    h = 0.01

    # Solve the system of differential equations using RK4
    t_values, y_values = solve_double_pendulum(t_span, y0, h, L1, L2, m1, m2)

    # Extract the solution
    theta1 = y_values[:, 0]
    theta2 = y_values[:, 2]

    # Write to files:
    file1 = open(loc1, "w")

    def writeToLst(targetFile, Lst1, Lst2, Lst3):
        length = len(Lst1)

        if(length == len(Lst2) == len(Lst3)):
            for i in range(length):
                elt1, elt2, elt3 = "{:.10f}".format(Lst1[i]), "{:.10f}".format(Lst2[i]), "{:.10f}".format(Lst3[i])
                targetFile.write(f"{elt1}\t{elt2}\t{elt3}\n")
            print('Data stored successfully.')
        else:
            print('Error, ists must be of the same length.')

    writeToLst(file1, t_values, theta1, theta2)

initCond1 = np.array([np.pi/2, 0, np.pi/2, 0])
doublePendulumCall(initCond1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

I would greatly appreciate your help with resolving the issues highlighted in the bold text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the animations to be in the same figure, they need to be created in the same call to `FuncAnimation`. What you do is make two different animations.

I would do this by storing the data in lists and zipping them to deal with each dataset. I pass those lists to the function called by `FuncAnimation` (`FuncAnimation` accepts arguments, but the documentation recommends using `functools.partial`). That way, everything is combined into one figure, as desired.

I also made some other minor changes, like using the `unpack=True` argument for `np.loadtxt` and extracting all the coordinates in one call (that's the benefit of numpy arrays).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from functools import partial

plt.close("all")


def calculate_coordinates(L1, L2, angle1, angle2):
    x1 = L1 * np.sin(angle1)
    y1 = -L1 * np.cos(angle1)
    x2 = x1 + L2 * np.sin(angle2)
    y2 = y1 - L2 * np.cos(angle2)
    return x1, y1, x2, y2


time, theta11, theta12 = np.loadtxt("DoublePendRes1.txt",
                                    delimiter="\t", unpack=True)
_, theta21, theta22 = np.loadtxt("DoublePendRes2.txt",
                                 delimiter="\t", unpack=True)

x11, y11, x12, y12 = calculate_coordinates(1, 1, theta11, theta12)
x21, y21, x22, y22 = calculate_coordinates(1, 1, theta21, theta22)

data = [[x11, y11, x12, y12], [x21, y21, x22, y22]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim([-2.5,2.5])
ax.set_ylim([-2.5,0.5])
line1, = ax.plot([], [], color="tab:blue")
line2, = ax.plot([], [], color="tab:orange")
trail1, = ax.plot([], [], color="tab:blue", alpha=0.5)
trail2, = ax.plot([], [], color="tab:orange", alpha=0.5)
lines = [line1, line2]
trails = [trail1, trail2]

def func_full(i, lines, trails, data):
    for (x1, y1, x2, y2), line, trail in zip(data, lines, trails):
        line.set_data([0, x1[i], x2[i]], [0, y1[i], y2[i]])
        trail.set_data(x2[i-20 if i > 20 else 0:i+1], 
                       y2[i-20 if i > 20 else 0:i+1])
        
func = partial(func_full, lines=lines, data=data, trails=trails)
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, func, frames=len(x11), interval=0)
```

[image]

As for why you had three figures, it's because you made one at the beginning of `animationCall` and two more when you called `pendulumAnimation` for each pendulum.

Comment: First of all thanks! Your results look great. But how, with the provided code do I display the animation? I tried using `plt.show()` but this doesn't work...

Comment: What I have done to make it work is I have added a for loop: `for i in range(num_frames):` which calls the function `func_full(i, lines, trails, data)` and then it adds a small pause `plt.pause(0.01)` after this loop I have added the `plt.show()` command. Now it does work, however I wonder if you intended to run it like so or maybe you wanted to run it in a different way?

Comment: @Mark `fig.show()` or `plt.show()` should work. It's the same as what you did originally. And looping through the frames and calling `plt.pause(0.01)` is a crude way to show an animation, but it doesn't let you save it (unless you save each frame as its own PNG and combine them afterwards). I assume your original code showed the figures, even though they were empty. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes you are right. But I already resolved the issue. Thanks for your help!